# Multiple Top 1 based on count

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table with multiple customers and multiple transaction dates.

```
Cust_ID Trans_Date
------- ----------
C01 2012-02-18
C01 2012-02-27
C01 2012-03-09
C02 2012-02-15
C02 2012-03-09
C03 2012-03-30
C01 2013-01-14
C02 2013-02-21
C03 2013-01-15
C03 2013-03-07
```

I want to find customers with most transaction in each year and the transactions for that customer.
Below is the result I am expecting.

```
Year    Cust_ID    nTrans
----    -------    ------
2012    C01        3
2013    C03        2
```

Can anybody help with the script? SQL Svr version 2012.

Thanking you in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "greatest N per group" problem.  It's usually solved with `row_number()`.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT YEAR(Trans_Date) Year,
        Cust_ID,
        COUNT(*) as nTrans,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(Trans_Date) ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY YEAR(Trans_Date),
        Cust_ID
)
SELECT Year,
    Cust_ID,
    nTrans
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Trans_Year
```

Strictly speaking, the `ROW_NUMBER()` here isn't ordered in a deterministic way.  As written, if there's a tie in the count, the query just returns one Cust_ID, but there's no guarantee which ID will be returned.  It should either be `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, Cust_ID` to make the results consistent, or you should use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` to allow for ties.

Comment: @THOMAS Might want to check my update.  The query as written doesn't handle ties.  If that's a concern you might need to look at using `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had the chance to test it but your solution should look something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(Trans_Date) AS Year, Cust_ID, COUNT(*) AS nTrans
FROM Transactions 
GROUP BY Year, Cust_ID
HAVING MAX(nTrans);
```

Have a look at [Group by functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max()` function on the column to find the largest value in the column. In this case you can apply `max(nTrans)`

eg:

```
SELECT MAX(column_name) FROM table_name;
```